# Local project workflow with Mercurial Hg and Bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, workflow, project, bitbucket

Usually I create my websites (PHP, HTML, CSS) local on my mac. I've MAMP and Mercurial (Hg) installed.

When I start a new project I draw up a new project directory in "htdocs" and begin with `hg init`. New files were added by `hg add` to the project or excluded in `.hgignore`. All changes in this project are completed with an `hg commit`.

Additional to the local project I push my whole project into a private repository to Bitbucket (`hg push https://bitbucket.org/MyUser/MyProjectRepository`). That works perfectly.

The problem begins when a second person works at the project at the same time. He clones with `hg clone https://bitbucket.org/MyUser/MyProjectRepository` my private Bitbucket repository.

When I change and commit a css file local on my mac, push it afterwords to Bitbucket and the second person changes something on his local css file at the same time he gets a merge problem when he he tries to push his changes to Bitbucket.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Questions should be in English: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Wrote my question in English.

Answer (score 1):

The second person needs to pull and merge your changes from the bitbucket repository before pushing his changes back.

Take a look at HGInit [here](http://hginit.com/02.html) for a great introduction to using Mercurial with a team.